# If in_array not found then use else statement

Tags: php

I am using the following code which checks Google geocode and based on the results returned it echos different responses.

My code at the moment

```
if (in_array("neighborhood", $newaddress["types"])) {
    echo $newaddress["long_name"];
} elseif (in_array("postal_town", $newaddress["types"])) {
    echo "neighborhood not found, but postal_town found"
} else {
    echo "Nothing found"
}
```

For some reason it is showing both for postal_town and neighborhood.

Not checking if one exists.

Basically if neighborhood exists it should only echo that code, if it does not exist it should check if postal_town exists, and if it does, echo that - if neither exist it should echo "nothing found"

Any ideas?

Comment: That should be correct. What does `$newaddress["types"]` contain?

Comment: You are missing semicolons at the end of the lines

Comment: Once you add the missing `;` so it will actually parse and execute: https://3v4l.org/FQ9Zg

Comment: @jack please take the tour to see how to use this stack exchange. https://stackoverflow.com/tour